# While fault make another http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request

I am trying to create a function that return a REST API response using nodeJS and express, request. This is a snippet of my code:

```
var express = require('express')
var httpRequest = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express() 

// callback -> the function you will call later
function getData1(callback) {

    request('http://www.my-server.com/data', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // call the function when the function finishes and also passed the `body`
        return callback(body);
      }
    })
} 


app.get('/get-data', function (request, response) {
    getData1(function(data1) {
        //do something with data
        response.send(data1);
    })
});
...
```

Thats works fine.
I need to make another request if the first one was fault.
Somthing like a loop ==> while request fault make another request and that for 3 times for example and then if th third one fault again return the error.

Would you have any idaeas ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out :

1. I set a simple counter in order to count how many times i have made the HTTP call.
2. I monitor this counter and if it goes above 3 i execute whatever logic i want.
3. I am incrementing the counter each time the HTTP call fails.
4. I call myself each time the HTTP fails , passing the incremented counter in arguments.
5. I am calling your `getData1` function with 1 as `counter` in your router. `(app.get)`

   `function getData1( callback , counter ) {
     if(counter >= 3){
     // Do Something , you have tried the HTTP 3 times already

     }else{
       request('http://www.my-server.com/data', function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
          callback(body);
         else{
         // Increment the counter 
            counter++;
         // Now call yourself with the new counter value
            getData1( callback , counter );
         }
       }
     })
   }`

   `app.get('/get-data', function (request, response) {
       getData1(function(data1) {
           //do something with data
           response.send(data1);
       } , 1 )
   });`